# How to position a router-outlet component as the top layer of the window?

Tags: html, css, angular, router-outlet

I'm building a layout in an Angular app that looks like this:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="router-wrapper">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

My issue is that I have a sidebar inside the componets loaded inside the `<router-outlet>`, this sidebar should be placed on top of everything on the screen; but no matter what I do with z-index or position absolute it always shows "behind" the navbar on top; can this be actually done?

Comment: can you provide code of your navbar and sidebar.. beacause i tried with dummy example and if we render any component on top of any component that always renders beyond the navbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-layouting)

Your wrapper cannot be position other than static if it is it becomes root for z-indexes for its children.

As an alternative, I would suggest using grid layout and push your topbar as part of layout controlled by the route (if you do that for sidebar why not for all).

[Further explanation of how z-index and its context works](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/z-index-explained-how-to-stack-elements-using-css-7c5aa0f179b3/)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done. If you are using the correct styles for the element it should be placed on the top of the page. If you haven't use any z-index value or position absolute for the nav-bar then simply you may need to make the position: absolute and z-index:10 for the sidemenu component to make it ahead of other elements. If you use any z-index value for the nav-bar then you need to put a higher z-index value than nav-bar for the sidebar.